# Does spark automatically cache some results?

Tags: caching, apache-spark

I run an action two times, and the second time takes very little time to run, so I suspect that spark automatically cache some results. But I did find any source.

Im using Spark1.4.

```
doc = sc.textFile('...')
doc_wc = doc.flatMap(lambda x: re.split('\W', x))\
            .filter(lambda x: x != '') \
            .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
            .reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y) 
%%time
doc_wc.take(5) # first time
# CPU times: user 10.7 ms, sys: 425 µs, total: 11.1 ms
# Wall time: 4.39 s

%%time
doc_wc.take(5) # second time
# CPU times: user 6.13 ms, sys: 276 µs, total: 6.41 ms
# Wall time: 151 ms
```

Answer (score 11):

From [the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#which-storage-level-to-choose):

> Spark also automatically persists some intermediate data in shuffle operations (e.g. reduceByKey), even without users calling persist. This is done to avoid recomputing the entire input if a node fails during the shuffle. We still recommend users call persist on the resulting RDD if they plan to reuse it.

The underlying filesystem will also be caching access to the disk.

Comment: Note that although the documentation uses the word "persist" this doesn't use the same caching mechanism as calls to `persist` or `cache`. Spark writes the shuffle output to disk which is not an RDD. This is important because a single node failure during shuffle can block *all* operations downstream of the shuffle.