# What happen if you count twice?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

What happen in spark when you are trying to do something like that:

```
def myMethod(myDF: Dataframe): Unit = {
    myDF....transformation....
    myDF.count() # 1
    myDF.count() # 2
}
```

I understand that at `#1` the dataframe will be materialized and all the transformation applied.

My question is, what happen at `#2` ?

Will the transformations happen again because the garbage collector would have destroyed the result from `#1` or because we are still in the same context, `#2` will return its result instantly ?

This is not the same as [Does spark automatically cache some results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31180592/does-spark-automatically-cache-some-results) because this is more about best practices than spark caching. To write the most performing code, what should I do?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd assume it would be evaluated again but that's not related to gc

Comment: So spark might cache some data but it will be unreliable, right ? It is safe to assume that it will recalculate but sometimes we can be lucky and it will reuse previously calculated results?